# How to create a tkinter page from a large matplot code

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, figure

I'm trying to make a GUI using tkinter to create a page with just one button that when clicked, will display the matplot that the code below produces. Not quite sure how to start with tkinter as I'm fairly new to it. I've seen videos giving solutions but they're all using very simple plots compared to mine.

`

```
import math
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot


u_inf = 5.0    


N = 500 
R = 5
x_center, y_center = 0.0, 0.0
theta = numpy.linspace(0.0, 2 * math.pi, 100)
x_cylinder, y_cylinder = (x_center + R * numpy.cos(theta),
                          y_center + R * numpy.sin(theta))
x_start, x_end = -10.1, 10.1           
y_start, y_end = -10.1, 10.1           
x = numpy.linspace(x_start, x_end, N)   
y = numpy.linspace(y_start, y_end, N)   
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)              # generates a mesh grid

class Panel:

    def __init__(self, xa, ya, xb, yb):

        self.xa, self.ya = xa, ya
        self.xb, self.yb = xb, yb
        
        self.xc, self.yc = (xa + xb) / 2, (ya + yb) / 2  
        self.length = math.sqrt((xb - xa)**2 + (yb - ya)**2) 
        
     
        if xb - xa <= 0.:
            self.beta = math.acos((yb - ya) / self.length)
        elif xb - xa > 0.:
            self.beta = math.pi + math.acos(-(yb - ya) / self.length)
        
        self.sigma = 1000.0  # source strength
        self.vt = 1.0  # tangential velocity
        self.cp = 1.0  # pressure coefficient

class Source:

    def __init__(self, strength, x, y):

        self.strength = strength
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    
    def velocity(self, X, Y):

        u = (self.strength / (2 * math.pi) * (self.x - X) / (X **2 + Y **2))
        v = (self.strength / (2 * math.pi) * (self.y - Y) / (X **2 + Y **2))
        return u, v
    
    def stream_function(self, X, Y):

        psi = (self.strength / (2 * math.pi) *
               numpy.arctan2((Y - self.y), (X - self.x)))
        return psi




strength_source = 5.0                 # strength of the source         
x_source, y_source = 0.0, 0.0          # location of the source


source = Source(strength_source,x_source, y_source)

u1, v1 = source.velocity(X, Y)
psi1 = source.stream_function(X, Y)

source_image = Source(strength_source, x_source, -y_source)
u2, v2 = source_image.velocity(X, Y)
psi2 = source_image.stream_function(X, Y)

N_panels = 100  # number of panels desired

x_ends = R * numpy.cos(numpy.linspace(0.0, 2 * math.pi, N_panels + 1))
y_ends = R * numpy.sin(numpy.linspace(0.0, 2 * math.pi, N_panels + 1))

panels = numpy.empty(N_panels, dtype=object)
for i in range(N_panels):
    panels[i] = Panel(x_ends[i], y_ends[i], x_ends[i + 1], y_ends[i + 1])
    


u = u1 + u2
v = v1 + v2
psi = psi1 + psi2


    
size = 12
pyplot.figure(figsize=(size, size))
pyplot.grid()
pyplot.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
pyplot.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
pyplot.plot(x_cylinder, y_cylinder,
            color='b', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
pyplot.plot(x_ends, y_ends,
            color='#CD2305', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
pyplot.scatter([p.xa for p in panels], [p.ya for p in panels],
               color='#CD2305', s=40)
pyplot.scatter([p.xc for p in panels], [p.yc for p in panels],
               color='k', s=40, zorder=3)
pyplot.legend(loc='best', prop={'size':16})
pyplot.streamplot(X, Y, u, v, density=4, linewidth=0.6, arrowsize=2, arrowstyle='->')
pyplot.xlim(-10.1, 10.1)
pyplot.ylim(-10.1, 10.1);
```

`

Comment: That is how you learn... start off with the simple ones and after you do a few then try to do your own and when you get stuck at a specific part you search for a solution or come back and ask about it here.

Comment: damn, that's crazy I never thought of that

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk)


class Panel:

    def __init__(self, xa, ya, xb, yb):

        self.xa, self.ya = xa, ya
        self.xb, self.yb = xb, yb

        self.xc, self.yc = (xa + xb) / 2, (ya + yb) / 2
        self.length = math.sqrt((xb - xa) ** 2 + (yb - ya) ** 2)

        if xb - xa <= 0.:
            self.beta = math.acos((yb - ya) / self.length)
        elif xb - xa > 0.:
            self.beta = math.pi + math.acos(-(yb - ya) / self.length)

        self.sigma = 1000.0  # source strength
        self.vt = 1.0  # tangential velocity
        self.cp = 1.0  # pressure coefficient


class Source:

    def __init__(self, strength, x, y):
        self.strength = strength
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def velocity(self, X, Y):
        u = (self.strength / (2 * math.pi) * (self.x - X) / (X ** 2 + Y ** 2))
        v = (self.strength / (2 * math.pi) * (self.y - Y) / (X ** 2 + Y ** 2))
        return u, v

    def stream_function(self, X, Y):
        psi = (self.strength / (2 * math.pi) *
               numpy.arctan2((Y - self.y), (X - self.x)))
        return psi

# calculations
N = 500
R = 5
x_center, y_center = 0.0, 0.0
theta = numpy.linspace(0.0, 2 * math.pi, 100)
x_cylinder, y_cylinder = (x_center + R * numpy.cos(theta),
                      y_center + R * numpy.sin(theta))
x_start, x_end = -12, 12
y_start, y_end = -12, 12
x = numpy.linspace(x_start, x_end, N)
y = numpy.linspace(y_start, y_end, N)
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)  # generates a mesh grid

strength_source = 5.0  # strength of the source
x_source, y_source = 0.0, 0.0  # location of the source

# create a source (object of class Source)
source = Source(strength_source, x_source, y_source)

# compute the velocity field and the stream-function on the mesh grid
u1, v1 = source.velocity(X, Y)

source_image = Source(strength_source, x_source, -y_source)
u2, v2 = source_image.velocity(X, Y)

N_panels = 100  # number of panels desired

# define the end-points of the panels
x_ends = R * numpy.cos(numpy.linspace(0.0, 2 * math.pi, N_panels + 1))
y_ends = R * numpy.sin(numpy.linspace(0.0, 2 * math.pi, N_panels + 1))

# define the panels
panels = numpy.empty(N_panels, dtype=object)
for i in range(N_panels):
    panels[i] = Panel(x_ends[i], y_ends[i], x_ends[i + 1], y_ends[i + 1])

u = u1 + u2
v = v1 + v2

# plot def for panels
size = 12

pyplot.grid()
pyplot.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
pyplot.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
pyplot.plot(x_cylinder, y_cylinder,
        color='b', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
pyplot.plot(x_ends, y_ends,
        color='#CD2305', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
pyplot.scatter([p.xa for p in panels], [p.ya for p in panels],
           color='#CD2305', s=40)
pyplot.scatter([p.xc for p in panels], [p.yc for p in panels],
           color='k', s=40, zorder=3)
pyplot.legend(loc='best', prop={'size': 16})
pyplot.streamplot(X, Y, u, v, density=4, linewidth=0.6, arrowsize=2, 
arrowstyle='->')
pyplot.xlim(-12, 12)
pyplot.ylim(-12, 12)


def plot():

    fig = pyplot.figure(1)
    # creating the Tkinter canvas
    # containing the Matplotlib figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
    canvas.draw()

    # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    # creating the Matplotlib toolbar
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window)
    toolbar.update()

    # placing the toolbar on the Tkinter window
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()


# the main Tkinter window
window = Tk()

# setting the title 
window.title('Plotting in Tkinter')

# dimensions of the main window
window.geometry("700x700")

# button that displays the plot
plot_button = Button(master=window, command=plot, height=2, width=10, text="Plot")

# place the button 
# in main window
plot_button.pack()

# run the gui
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).